# How do you get the params from a URL after running it with Python requests?

Tags: python, http, get, python-requests

I know how to do it with a current URL e.g.

```
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': ['value2', 'value3']}

>>> r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
>>> print(r.url)
```

But what about if after you visit a URL, such as one with OAuth, for example

```
authorize_url = facebook.get_authorize_url(**params)
requests.get(authorized_url)
```

The URL will then direct to one such as `https://localhost:5000/authorized?code=AQCvF`. How do I get the `code=AQCvF`?

I could probably do something like, get the address of the current browser and then parse the URL, but is there a cleaner way?

---

Complete code is below:

**index.j2**

```
<p><a href="/facebook-login">Login with Facebook</a></p>
```

**routes.py**

```
app.add_route('/facebook-login', LoginHandler('index.j2'))
app.add_route('/authorized', AuthorizedHandler('index.j2'))
```

**handlers.py**

```
from rauth.service import OAuth2Service
import requests
import os

# rauth OAuth 2.0 service wrapper
graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
facebook = OAuth2Service(name='facebook',
                         authorize_url='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
                         access_token_url=graph_url + 'oauth/access_token',
                         client_id=FB_CLIENT_ID,
                         client_secret=FB_CLIENT_SECRET,
                         base_url=graph_url)


class AuthorizedHandler(TemplateHandler):

    def on_get(self, req, res):
        code = self.requests.get['code']
        data = dict(code=code, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)
        session = facebook.get_auth_session(data=data)

        # response
        me = session.get('me').json()
        print('me', me)

        UserController.create(me['username'], me['id'])


class LoginHandler(TemplateHandler):

    async def on_get(self, req, res):
        # visit URL and client authorizes
        params = {'response_type': 'code',
                  'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI}

        webbrowser.open(facebook.get_authorize_url(**params))

        response = requests.get(facebook.get_authorize_url(**params))
        print(response.url)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can get the [`.url` attribute from the `Response` object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.url) - this would be the *final* response URL:

```
response = requests.get(authorized_url)
print(response.url)
```

Then, you can [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) the url to extract the GET parameters:

```
In [1]: from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse

In [2]: url = "https://localhost:5000/authorized?code=AQCvF"

In [3]: parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)
Out[3]: {'code': ['AQCvF']}
```

Comment: That seems completely logical to me! Unfortunately, the response that response.url is returning is my `REDIRECT_URI` which is in this case `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` and not the URL with the `code` param I'm looking for.

Comment: On the other hand, the correct URL will appear in the address bar when I add `webbrowser.open(authorized_url)`

Comment: @Adrienne gotcha, could you please provide your complete code so far? I suspect it might be that you need a real browser to get to the redirection chain finale, want to test it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, just appended it! Yeah, that is what I am also suspecting.

Comment: I suspect the lack of redirection has something to do with needing a Session that stores a cookie. But the rauth documentation suggests we can obtain the code param from the URL and pass it into the session, which seems contradictory (https://rauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) `# the code should be returned upon the redirect from the authorize step,
# be sure to use it here (hint: it's in the URL!)
session = facebook.get_auth_session(data={'code': 'foo',
                                           'redirect_uri': redirect_uri})`

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work fine if you were using a synchronous Python framework, but it appears you are using an async framework, as implied by the `async def on_get(self, req, res)`.

You will either have to write an async HTTP request function, use aiohttp.web, or your framework might have one built in and you can replace `requests.get(facebook.get_authorize_url(**params))` with `res.redirect(facebook.get_authorize_url(**params))`.